# Выполнение после функции JQuery

Tags: jquery

Как выполнить что-то после выполнение предыдущей функции? Например:

```
$(".ua_zoom").draggable({ revert: true}, function(){
   alert("1");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы используете https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ и вам нужно, чтобы выполнялся код после перемещения.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({

      revert: true,

      start: function() {
        [Начало]
      },

      drag: function() {
        [Перемещение]
      },

      stop: function() {
        [Конец]
      }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помог.

Comment: @Владимир бог всегда рад помочь. И да, у меня мания величия)